# how do i fix this logical error for displaying with 3d vector

Tags: c++

i am receiving logical error where the expected ouput is not displayed, it should display do new, but only do is displayed.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  
    vector<vector<vector<string>>> vec = {{{"do", "new"}}};
    
  auto i=0,j=0,x=0;
  
  for(i=0;i<vec.size();i++){
      for(j=0;j<vec[i].size();j++){
          for(x=0;x<vec[j].size();x++){
              cout << vec[i][j][x] << " ";
          }
      }
      
  }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Typo: `x<vec[j].size()` should be `x<vec[i][j].size()`.

Comment: `for (auto& v1 : vec) for (auto& v2 : v1) for (auto& s : v2) std::cout << i << " ";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like you missed to index `vec[i][j]` while getting the size of the innermost vector.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  
    vector<vector<vector<string>>> vec = {{{"do", "new"}}};
    
  auto i=0,j=0,x=0;
  
  for(i=0;i<vec.size();i++){
      for(j=0;j<vec[i].size();j++){
          for(x=0;x<vec[i][j].size();x++){
              cout << vec[i][j][x] << " ";
          }
      }
      
  }
    return 0;
}
```